# How can I access this.$route from within vue-apollo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo

I'm constructing a GraphQL query using `vue-apollo` and `graphql-tag`.

If I hardcode the ID I want, it works, but I'd like to pass the current route ID to Vue Apollo as a variable.

**Does work** (hardcoded ID):

```
  apollo: {
    Property: {
      query: PropertyQuery,
      loadingKey: 'loading',
      variables: {
        id: 'my-long-id-example'
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I'm unable to do this:

**Doesn't work** (trying to access this.$route for the ID):

```
  apollo: {
    Property: {
      query: PropertyQuery,
      loadingKey: 'loading',
      variables: {
        id: this.$route.params.id
      }
    }
  }
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT**: Full script block to make it easier to see what's going on:

```
<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const PropertyQuery = gql`
  query Property($id: ID!) {
    Property(id: $id) {
      id
      slug
      title
      description
      price
      area
      available
      image
      createdAt
      user {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
      }
    }
  }
`

export default {
  name: 'Property',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Property',
      property: {}
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    Property: {
      query: PropertyQuery,
      loadingKey: 'loading',
      variables: {
        id: this.$route.params.id // Error here!
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thanks for the reply. It's an object that sits on the default export. I have updated my question to show this in context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Readimg the [documentation](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo#simple-query)( see Reactive parameters section) of vue-apollo you can use vue reactive properties by using `this.propertyName`. So just initialize the route params to a data property as then use it in you apollo object like this

```
export default {
  name: 'Property',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Property',
      property: {},
      routeParam: this.$route.params.id
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    Property: {
      query: PropertyQuery,
      loadingKey: 'loading',
         // Reactive parameters
      variables() {
        return{
            id: this.routeParam
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep this worked! Thank you. So variables becomes a function that returns an object instead of directly being an object itself. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo happy to help and to be frank i read the docs and learned something new, so thanks to you too :)

Answer (score 12):

You can't have access to "this" object like that:

```
variables: {
  id: this.$route.params.id // Error here! 
}
```

**But you can like this:**

```
variables () {   
    return {
         id: this.$route.params.id // Works here!  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer is correct for the poster's example, it's more complex than necessary if you're using simple queries.

In this case, `this` is not the component instance, so you can't access `this.$route`

```
apollo: {
  Property: gql`{object(id: ${this.$route.params.id}){prop1, prop2}}`
}
```

However, you can simply replace it with a function, and it will work as you might expect.

```
apollo: {
  Property () {
    return gql`{object(id: ${this.$route.params.id}){prop1, prop2}}`
  }
}
```

No need for setting extra props.